# How Do I Create a User Profile With Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, profile

I really like how devise offers an easy to use registration system out of the box but I'm having trouble extending it to do what I need. I need to create a public user profile for each user that shows their information like name, email, bio, and more info. I've done this in the past before with a users/show function but since devise doesn't provide any easily editable controllers, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. I've already run rails generate devise:views to copy the devise views to my app but I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want users to update their profile at the same time they create their account?  If so, you can setup an associated Profile model with the User model.  Using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you can then create a record for the nested model on devise user registration submit/creation.

Here's a [great screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) covering nested models and I also suggest you search other devise relate SO posts as this question has been discussed before.

There is an alternative approach, that is simpler to implement — only allow registered users edit/update their profile.  This way you don't have to alter the Devise views and you can setup the various CRUD actions via a separate non-devise controller.

Throw in an Access Control List (ACL) solution such as CanCan (there are other alternatives too!) and you can even allow other users view profiles but deny access to edit/destroy etc.